# PRISM + MEF: usercontrol or page?

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism

For WPF Prism + MEF, most samples use usercontrol, is there any issue NOT to use page instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well `Pages` are intended for [XAML Browser Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) and should be contained inside Frame or a NavigationWindow. On the other hand `UserControl` can be contained inside a `Window` or another control.

XBAP run from Internet Explorer. Most samples apparently are not XBAP so that's why they don't use `Page` control. If it's what you want there is no problem using `Page` for Prism application. And MEF has nothing to do with this question.